# Buffered string mangled

Tags: c, xml, string, buffer

I am making an XML formatter in C. It's going really well, but my previous approach (direct printf at each character) wouldn't print the right amount of spaces for each line. Therefore, I made a string buffer and `realloc`ed it each time to print a new character. (I know it's not the best, but I don't care.) The new code won't clear the buffer or detect newlines correctly.

```
void bufprint(char **line, char *poo) {
    /*SNIP old code without realloc*/
    *line=realloc(*line,strlen(*(line))+1+strlen(poo));
    strcpy(*line+strlen(*line),poo);
}
```

And buf is declared like `char *buf=malloc(1);`.
bufprint is called: `bufprint(&buf,"<");`.

Code for clearing buffer:

```
    if (new) {
        new=False;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < level; i++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%s",buf);
        free(buf);
        buf=malloc(1);
        printf("\n");
        //printf("BUFFER CLEARED! --------------");
        //printf("New buffer: %s %d",buf,strlen(buf));
    }
```

Sample output:

```
<
 <root>
  <root><element num="1">
  This is element 1

 </element>
  </element><element num="2">
  This is element 2

   <subelement>
   <subelement>This is a sub-element

  </subelement>
  </subelement>Self-closing tag:

  <br />
 <br /></element>
</root>
```

Comment: Do you ever initialize buf[0] to '\0' after doing buf=malloc(...)? If not, strlen(buf) may crash or return a length, bigger than there's memory allocated to buf.

Comment: Am I reading your question correctly -- you're expecting free/malloc to "clear" a buffer?  If so, I'm afraid that's not going to work in C; the malloc'd mem needs to be initialized.

Answer (score 4):

The `malloc(1)` call will *not* zero out the byte that was just allocated. You must do this yourself, otherwise your newly allocated memory might contain some random nonzero byte.

```
buf = malloc(1);
buf[0] = '\0';
```

If this does not solve your problem, then the bug may lie somewhere else that you haven't shown us.

Comment: I actually found this out a before you did; I was just too lazy. Thanks anyway!